# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (...) Check the render method of `Carlist`

Tags: reactjs, import, components

I am following a book about fullstack developement in Spring + React. I am a total newbie and I followed the code provided in a book, but I am getting an error provided in the title. I know it may have something to do with imports, but I am stumped as to where the issue may be.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Carlist from './components/Carlist';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AppBar position="static" color="default">
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit">
            CarList
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Carlist></Carlist>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Carlist.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {SERVER_URL} from '../constants.js'
import ReactTable from "react-table";

class Carlist extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { cars: []};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(SERVER_URL + 'api/cars')
    .then((response) => response.json()) 
    .then((responseData) => { 
      this.setState({ 
        cars: responseData._embedded.cars,
      }); 
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err)); 
  }


  render() {
    const columns = [{
      Header: 'Brand',
      accessor: 'brand'
     }, {
      Header: 'Model',
      accessor: 'model',
    }, {
      Header: 'Color',
      accessor: 'color',
    }, {
      Header: 'Year',
      accessor: 'year',
    }, {
      Header: 'Price €',
      accessor: 'price',
    },]

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ReactTable data={this.state.cars} columns={columns} 
          filterable={true}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Carlist;
```

Comment: right before this.setState, can you log the response with `console.log(responseData)`

Comment: I tried doing that, but it seems like the code dtoes not even get to this point for whatever reason. I'd also like to notice, that the example worked fine befor I tried adding a react table. It works fine with a regular html table. Also, API is responding through Postman without issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the issue. For anyone wondering, the way of rendering the tables in react-table has changed significantly in version 7. The solution is either to downgrade to version 6 or follow the documentation in version 7 and adjust the code.

For comparison:
V7 implementation: https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/master/examples/basic/src/App.js
V6 implementation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table-v6#example